# Prove that Pb(x) = x / $||$x$||$ if $||$x$||$ $\gt$ 1 or x if $||$x$||$ $\leq$ 1.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

Define the closed unit ball B $\subset$ R<sup>n</sup> by B := {x $\in$ R<sup>n</sup> $|$ $||$x$||$ $\leq$ 1} where $||$.$||$ denotes the Euclidean norm of R<sup>n</sup>, i.e., $||$x$||$ = $\sqrt{< x,x >}$ for x $\in$ R<sup>n</sup>.

Prove that P<sub>B</sub>(x) = x / $||$x$||$ (supposed to be a fraction)
if $||$x$||$ $\gt$ 1 or x if $||$x$||$ $\leq$ 1.

P<sub>B</sub>(x) is the closest point to x in B

I am having troubles getting started with this proof. Could someone give me a hand?

Comment: You still have to tell us what $P_B(x)$ is.

Comment: it is a projection function

Comment: There are many projections defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$. What is the precise definition of $P_B$?

Comment: P_B is the closest point to x in B

Comment: Hint: Think of 2D space. Draw the norm ball, which is essentially a circle at the center in 2D. Take any point x in the plane. If you draw a line from the center to that point x, then this line will intersect with the exterior of the norm ball, what is that point?